# How do i block acces to a directory except for the server with IIS7?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

How do i block access to all people except the server to view images?
already bugging me for 1 week now.

my page has <\img src="Catalog/image.jpg">

but i must block access to HOST/Catalog/image.jpg.

is this even possible with IIS7?
with .htaccess i would just do:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

i did try the following:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <authorization>
            <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
            <add accessType="Deny" users="?" />
            <add accessType="Allow" roles="Administrators" />
        </authorization>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: You can write a handler to display images, and on the handler if there is no parent page/URL referrer then do not supply the image.

Comment: sounds promising. could you post an example? i'm only programming in ASP.NET because school requires me too so only at it for 7 weeks. so i have no idea how to write an handler or even know what it is